# How to create a motor startup tone with a BLHeli ESC?

Tags: esc, blheli

I am using a 32bit DShot1200 ESC, how can I make a custom startup sound for when the drone is powered on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove your props, plug your quad into the computer and plug in a battery.

You then need to go into BLHeli Suite 32 and read your ESC setup.

You will then have options to sync ESC music and you can upload your tones.

A more detailed guide with lots of detail for each step can be found here: https://oscarliang.com/blheli-32-custom-startup-tone-music/